# How to remove wsl distro from windows?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I've installed docker desktop on my windows 10.
Then I discovered WSL.
After writing command `wsl -l -v` I saw that I had 2 distros:

```
docker-desktop-data
docker-desktop
```

I've also installed Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft Store and now I also have

```
Ubuntu-20.04
```

Now I want to get rid of these 2. I don't need so many of them. I know that docker-desktop-data contains images docker-desktop contains the docker infrastructure. But it's still unclear to me and confusing. I want to use Ubuntu-20.04 for my docker experiments only.

How do I delete these?

[image]

Comment: Probably a more appropriate question for Super User, but it seems Docker-based questions are usually "borderline" accepted here on Stack Overflow. While I've never done it (so I'm not providing this as an answer, since I can't be sure), you should be able to uninstall Docker Desktop, then go through the "normal" Ubuntu-based [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) for Docker inside the Ubuntu instance.  You'll lose the ability to run Docker from PowerShell, but still have "normal" Linux based docker commands -- It sounds like that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 17):

If after uninstalling docker you still see docker-desktop-data

You can remove it with the following command:

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
```

You can list distros with the following command:

```
wsl -l
```

Comment: Make sure you do not surround the name with double quotes. It can't handle that.

Answer (score 12):

Per the wsl2 docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands

wsl --unregister

will remove a linux distro you no longer need.